# Where current timestamp between two unix timestamps SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to make a query where time() is between date_start and date_end
i tried:

```
date_start > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND date_end < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

and

```
WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
```

Still it does not workout for me. Tried CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() too.

Mysql

```
id  item_id percentage  rabatcode   date_start  date_end
9   6       50          XXY-GGS-82  1323817200  1324422000
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the date_start and date_end values as well as the schema definition?

Comment: Should work, unless your columns are not of a proper date type.

Comment: See updated @hafichuk . The columns are int 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare `NOW()` against the values via `FROM_UNIXTIME()`:

```
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(date_start) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(date_end)
```

Ideally, if it is possible for you to modify your database structure, it is usually much better to store dates as MySQL's native `DATETIME` type, owing to the fact that MySQL's date processing functions work with the date types without conversion.

Comment: Thank you this worked!! can you tell me why my current_timestamp comparing with the other timestamps, wouldnt work?

Comment: @Karem `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a synonym for `NOW()` so you could use that instead.  But you would need to convert it to a UNIX timestamp from the native MySQL datetime format as `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`.  Above, I did the opposite, converting your two UNIX timestamps to MySQL format instead...

Answer (score 2):

You mention in the title of your question that you want to check when the current time is between to UNIX timestamps, so you need to use the [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function:

```
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() BETWEEN date_start AND date_end
```

`NOW()` returns a string (from the manual: `'2007-12-15 23:50:26'`) so it won't work for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` twice. You should look into converting your dates to a different format and comparing them to `NOW()` (if they cannot be compared to `NOW()` already.

Comment: would you be able to provide a reference for not being able to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` twice in a query?

Comment: AFAIK, [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) is the same as `NOW()`